# $.ajax POST throws error in Internet Explorer but no other browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Hello I am trying to write a method that will post information to another domain and get a simple response back. I have this functionality working in Chrome and Firefox, but all versions of IE are not functioning correctly. Here is my code:

```
function getCode(email, password, firstname, lastname){
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "http://localhost:61660/Account/TestMemberStatus",
        data: {email:  email, password: password, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            ContinuePart2(result, email, firstname, lastname);
        },
        error: function(result){
            ContinuePart2("error");
        }
    });
}
```

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and the error I am receiving in IE is "Error: Access is denied.\r\n"

the backend is a .NET MVC3 site with an exposed method that returns a JSON string. I have added the follwing headers:

```
filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

UPDATE: This is a cross domain call

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I assume the error is being thrown when attempting to make the AJAX request, rather than when handling the response? If so, what's the URL of the page making the request? If not, what does `ContinuePart2()` do?

Comment: ContinuePart2 just updates a few elements with the data. The error handler fires each time. I also should mention that this is Cross Domain, I will update the question with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer only supports CORS partially. It's starting from IE10 that you could hope for a full CORS support of XHR. For example IE8 [supports CORS with the XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28VS.85%29.aspx) object which is proprietary.

Comment: So essentially, this is not possible to support in IE7+?

Comment: It's possible. In IE8 you could use the native `XDomainRequest` object to send your AJAX request. As far as IE7 is concerned, I honestly have no idea. It's been so many years that I have stopped worrying about this browser.